# PySide6. Как остановить выполнение функции вызванной в threading.Timer при закрытии GUI?

Tags: таймер, python-3.9, pyside6, closeevent

Создал  `self.work_timer = threading.Timer(0.5, self.blue_connect)` таймер, который стартует при нажатии на кнопку, и внутри `self.blue_connect` крутится код в бесконечном цикле. Далее переопределил `closeEvent`

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    self.work_function.cancel()
    event.accept()
```

В нём написал отключение таймера, однако после завершения работы GUI, скрипт всё-равно работает в фоновом режиме

Comment: То есть, правильно ли я понял, что каждые 0,5 сек вы запускаете по одной функции blue_connect внутри которого (каждого) бесконечный цикл?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin да, если есть способ запустить функцию лишь один раз на отдельном потоке, с возможностью прервать выполнение при необходимости, буду рад узнать про таковой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В бесконечном цикле крутился код bluetooth соединения. Достаточно было закрыть соединение с клиентом и вызвать исключение, тем самым через `pass` завершить цикл, и соответственно - код